# For Loop Syntax: Create New UIView . .

Tags: ios, xcode, for-loop, uiview, xib

I'm new to iOS, and I want to construct a for loop that says "for every object in my array, create a new UIView". I know this would be considered very basic and simple, but how would I code this?

Comment: for(int c = 0 ; c <= arr.count; c++ )
    {
       UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
       //set view frame..etc..
    
    }

Comment: Atleast try something, don't just come here and ask for do my work.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because No effort done by OP.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar How do you know I didn't try? I'm new to the site and I'm new to the tech world, I would not ask for help if I did not need it. I simply asked for an example of SYNTAX. You can either help me or not, please don't be negative. Thank you.

Comment: Please show the object used to create the `UIView` as there will properties of that object that affect how the `UIView` is configured.

Comment: Thank you! @BhushanUparkar Wish I could +1!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (Object *object in Array) {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:???];

    // Do whatever else you need here

    [??? addSubView:view];
}
```

I have done "for (Object *object in Array)" in case you need data from said object inside your views subviews.

Comment: No I will try this . . .

Comment: This worked great! Wish I could vote up, but it says I need 10 reputations. Otherwise +100!!! :) Thanks!

Comment: No problem, good to hear it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to read the documentation for UICollectionViewController and UITableViewController. They manage collections of subviews for you.